# Resize canvas and object wrong top calculation

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, fabricjs2

I'm trying to resize canvas and all object in it.
After load the Json and set the main width and height of the canvas i just try to resize canvas.
After resize the canvas and the object some of the object don't respect the top value(or not is calculated right i my function).

I'm runnung on fabricjs 1.7.7

```
var j      = JSON.parse(json);
setTimeout(function(){
        canvas.loadFromDatalessJSON(JSON.stringify(j), canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), function(o, object){
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
            var newWidth    =   500;
        if (canvas.width != newWidth) {
          var scaleMultiplier = newWidth / canvas.width;
          var objects = canvas.getObjects();
          var factorX = newWidth / canvas.getWidth();
          var factorY = newWidth / canvas.getHeight();
          for (var i in objects) {
              objects[i].scaleX = objects[i].scaleX;
              objects[i].scaleY = objects[i].scaleY;
              objects[i].left = factorX * objects[i].left;
              objects[i].top = factorY * objects[i].top ;
              objects[i].setCoords();
          };

          canvas.setWidth(canvas.getWidth() * factorX);
          canvas.setHeight(canvas.getHeight() * factorY);
          canvas.renderAll();
          canvas.calcOffset();
      };
    }, 3000);
}, 2000);
```

Here is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W3b3r/3stbg75d/

(in this fiddle there is some timeout to show at first the result of load json and after the result of resize)
In this case i got some element that don't have the same position after resize.

I also try only the command centerH() without scaling but the result is the same i got some of picture out of viewport.

Thanks in advance.
Best.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/6eb2skx7/1/
You need to multiply the `object.scaleX` and `object.scaleY` with `factorX`

Comment: Hi Marius, thanks for your help but my resize is a 500 x 500 px and i need to fit all image to full canvas width and height. if i scaleY and scaleX the picture rendered is smallest respect to 500 x 500 px